# @media CSS Help - adjusting text to display for responsive mobile

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, hidden

Below is my CSS and im trying to get this to display as 2 lines on mobile devices.  Right now it displays and one long sentence and need to scroll on mobile to read it.

```
<!-- promo banner -->
.site-tools-bar {
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
    height: 42px;
    min-width: 1015px;
}


.site-tools-bar .site-tools-wrapper {
    width: 1015px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 12px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.site-tools-bar a.header-promo {
    font-family: "Montserrat",sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 15px;
    float: center;
}

.site-tools-bar a.header-promo .promo-code {
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

Comment: The html would be helpful. Maybe set up a JSFiddle.

Comment: @hopkins-matt or just include it as * gasp * a Stack Snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a **very** basic solution just to get you started (only two screen sizes) - you can get the idea: just create as many sizes as you like and declare the element width (and any other screen-specific features) for each one. Everything inside the element should be scaled in percentages.

```
    .site-tools-bar {
        box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
        height: 42px;
        margin: 0px auto;
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
    }
    @media screen and (min-width: 321px) {
      .site-tools-bar {
      width:1015px;
      }
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
      .site-tools-bar {
      width:320px;
      }
    }
    .site-tools-wrapper {
        width: calc(100% - 24px);
        margin: 0px auto;
        padding: 12px 0px;
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
    }

    .site-tools-bar a.header-promo {
        font-family: "Montserrat",sans-serif;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 15px;
        float: center;
    }

    .site-tools-bar a.header-promo .promo-code {
        color: #ff0000;
    }
```